# iptables advice with upd ports blocking in debian linux

Tags: debian, iptables

please advice:

I add next iptables rules:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -p udp --dport 1700:1750 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 3 -p udp -m udp --dport 1812 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -p udp -m udp --dport 1813 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -p udp -m udp --dport 5950:6050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -p udp -m udp --dport 499:510 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 5 -p udp -m udp --dport 4490:4550 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT 20 -p udp -j DROP
```

But, after apply: ipsec, l2tp and openvp udp port 6000 stops working

Advice, what is wrong?

Here is my udp services:

```
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:500 0.0.0.0:* 3115/charon
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:1701 0.0.0.0:* 2885/xl2tpd
udp 0 0 162.243.256.150:6000 0.0.0.0:* 2818/openvpn
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:4500 0.0.0.0:* 3115/charon
udp6 0 0 :::500 :::* 3115/charon
```

Comment: cross posted: http://serverfault.com/questions/591718/iptables-rules-advice-in-debian-linux

Answer (score 1):

The `OUTPUT` chain will better fit on servers that are "clients" of this services(like an office that have a openvpn connection with the main office).

You will have to `ACCEPT` the traffic that is incoming to your server and the output of those related connections depending on the service(like ftp/tcp that creates new related connections to transfer). Example on the openvpn service:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 2818 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The last line you dont need to duplicate to every service.